# How can i change Currency in SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, api, soap, currency

I'm Using SOAP API V2 to develop an Android application, everything looks good so far except the currency, its showing the basic currency USD, how can i change it ?

My Basic Currency is **AED**, But when i using **SOAP** its showing in USD everywhere(product price, subtotal, total , discount, shipping),am using **ET Currency Manager** in my Store.

Using : Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 and SOAP API V1.

Thanks in advance